# How to completely uninstall an Android system app?

Tags: java, android, uninstallation

I am developing an Android system app. For uninstalling it, merely deleting the APK from `system/app` sometimes does not remove its shared preferences.

So, what is the proper method of completely uninstalling a system app which will ensure that it removes everything associated with this app?

Comment: Are you deleting apk? Which command you are using

Comment: @PankajKumar :Using ES file explorer app,going to system/app,selecting my app and just deleting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems you are doing this on a rooted device. So, the below command will do your task:

```
adb shell rm /system/app/APK_NAME.apk      // Removes apk file from /system/app/ location
adb shell pm clear com.yourapp.packagename // Removes application data
```

It may need a root permission, so before running above commands, you should run the below commands to take root privilege:

```
adb root
adb remount
```

and then run the above commands.

Comment: Should this be executed when the device is running,or can I use this in the recovery mode as well?

Comment: when the device is running.

Comment: What is the difference between `adb shell rm` + `adb shell pm clear` combo and [`adb uninstall`](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/92130/78385)?

Answer (score 5):

This is a way to remove/uninstall (not from the phone as it comes back with factory reset) almost *ANY* app WITHOUT root INCLUDING system apps (hint: the annoying update app that updates your phone line it or not can usually be found by grepping for "ccc")

### In order to do this you need to:

1. have adb installed
2. have usb debugging turned on

   a. in the phone go to settings --> system --> about phone --> tap rapidly 7 times on "Build number"

   b. in the phone go to settings --> system --> Developer options

   c. under "Debugging" turn on "USB debugging"
3. have the phone connected to via a USB cable

### The following example kills the presidential alert app:

```
adb shell pm uninstall --user 0 com.android.cellbroadcastreceiver
```

### It would look like this:

```
$ adb shell pm uninstall --user 0 com.android.cellbroadcastreceiver
Success
```

### To view users run:

```
adb shell pm list users
```

### you will see something like this:

```
$ adb shell pm list users                                                
Users:
     UserInfo{0:Owner:13} running
```

The first number "0" is the user ID number then seperated by ":" next comes the "name" or username of the user ("Owner" is above example) then after another ":" the group number (13).  All you need is the user number/UID "0".  It is VERY rare to see more than one user.  The Android OS can support > 1 user but I have yet to ever see it used.  There may be a few apps you might see a response of "Failed" for but 95%+ you should see "Success".

### To list all the apps you can run:

```
$ adb shell pm list packages [-f]
```

The -f switch is for a "Full" listing which outputs is this format:
package://.apk=com.app.name
where "package:" is always first followed by the full path to the apk file of the app then followed immediately with "=" then the dotten notated app name - note there are no spaces to the left/right of "=".  Below is an example:

```
package:/system/priv-app/MmsService/MmsService.apk=com.android.mms.service
package:/data/app/aws.apps.netPortDb-1/base.apk=aws.apps.netPortDb
package:/oem/priv-app/Ignite/Ignite.apk=com.LogiaGroup.LogiaDeck
```

You will notice there are 3 starting directories [/system, /data, /oem] The system apps usually start with /system; apps you install usually start with /data; and apps force installed by who you got the phone through (VZW, ATT, etc) usually start with /oem.  While is is not the case 100% of the time is ios very often the way apps are placed.